# Remove memory limit

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, memory

I have ms SQL server and table by name 'files'. Table column type 'image' (or blob) there saved pdf files. And I try to select in PHP. My code like

```
$sql = "SELECT DATALENGTH(file) as len, file FROM files WHERE id = 1";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $fileLength = $row['len'];
    $file = $row['file'];
    break;
} 

echo $fileLength;
echo strlen($file);
```

In display showed 1448484 and 64512. Variable $file took just 64512.
File memory in database 1.4 MB. In PHP code variable $file takes just 64KB. In fact, variable size of the $file must 1.4 MB. Why? How change this limit? Help me, please. Sorry for my English

Comment: You can't reliably get large objects like that. Check http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php for more info.

Comment: You should upload the file in some folder, this is the preferred approach, if you store file as blob in database, it will increase your database size unnecessarily.